# How to verify one certificate with public key of another

Tags: java, encryption, certificate, x509certificate, x509

I have two x509Certificates

```
X509Certificate a;
X509Certificate b;
```

I would like to verify the signature of b with public key of a, where a is the issuer of b.

What I have so far is:

```
 public static boolean verify(String algorithm, byte[] content, byte[] signature, X509Certificate certificate) {
  try {
     Signature s = Signature.getInstance(algorithm, PROVIDER);
     s.initVerify(certificate);
     s.update(content);
     return s.verify(signature);
  } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException | SignatureException e) {
     throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
  }
```

}

and I invoke method:

```
 verify(a.getSigAlgName(), a.getSignature(), b.getSignature(), b);
```

But this returns always false???

Could you please, help me to understand what might be the reason above method vertify(..) to return always false.

**EDIT:**

X509Certificate has a method verify(Public key).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> would like do decrypt contents of b with public key of a:

No you wouldn't. Certificates aren't encrypted.

What you're really trying to do here is *verify* a certificate, which is done via its public key, obtained either from the certificate itself or from a second source of the same public key.

Verifying it with the public key of a *different* certificate doesn't begin to make sense.

In any case`X509Certificate` already contains a sufficient `verify()` method.

Comment: My goal is to check if certificate b is signed by a. I didn't find solution for this, so I have thought that this was the approach, but you are right, thank you. Do you know, how I can verify if b is signed by a?

Comment: I can only repeat what I said above. The `Certificate.verify()` method is already sufficient. You supply the public key of the entity that is supposed to have signed it. You don't need all this other code.

Comment: Thank you very much, I found out that x509Certificate has a method verify(Public key) which exactly what I am looking for

Comment: That's what I told you. Twice. There's no 'I found out' about it.